# How to preserve selected cell after datasource refresh?

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

I need to paint a selected cell in blue in a grid and refresh the datasource every 10 seconds.  However, the selected cell loses the previously added class after refresh.

How to preserve the added class on refresh?

Here is a plunk - https://plnkr.co/edit/ASB4zi5dzMSNTxcquLCa

```
ngOnInit() {
      setInterval(() => this.grid.instance.refresh(), 10000); // 10 secs
}

selectCell(event) {
    event.jQueryEvent.target.className += ' blue-border'; // add class to element
    console.log(event.jQueryEvent.target);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you solve this with help of CSS styles and DxDataGrid multiple selection mode (use 'ctrl'+'click' to select multiple items ):

https://plnkr.co/edit/9vgR7X41jg0KKFeDpUKO?p=preview

Use following sample to turn on multiple selection:

```
<dxo-selection 
    mode="multiple" 
    [showCheckBoxesMode]="false"
></dxo-selection>
```

To customise a component use `/deep/` selector.

If this way is not acceptable for some reason, you can try to use [onRowPrepared](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Configuration/#onRowPrepared) action to customise cells appearance.

Comment: The first suggestion was not very useful as I am interested in selecting cells rather than rows. I ended up resolving using [onCellPrepared](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#cellPrepared) to check against the last selected cell's row and columnIndex and adding the class when the condition was good.